# Change data type of a column from Text to Number

Tags: vba, excel

I need to update the data type of a column from Text to Number so that I can use it to perform further calculations. The below code is not working for me. Could you please suggest a workaround to this problem?

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim Rowcount As Long


    Worksheets("Input").Select
    Rowcount = Application.CountA(Range("C:C"))
    Set rRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AQ2:AQ" & Rowcount)

    For Each rCell In rRange.Cells

        rCell.Value = rCell.Value * 1

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `NumberFormat` to a numeric format before running that loop.

```
Set rRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AQ2:AQ" & Rowcount)
rRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0" ' anything but "@" / text

For Each rCell In rRange.Cells
    Debug.Assert IsNumeric(rCell.Value) 'will break if not true
    rCell.Value = rCell.Value * 1
Next rCell
```

I added that `Assert` call to break execution if an error is ever encountered; if `rRange` contains any cell errors, `rCell.Value * 1` will raise a *type mismatch* run-time error.

Alternatively you could just skip error cells, if error cells are supposed to be expected:

```
For Each rCell In rRange.Cells
    If Not IsError(rCell.Value) Then
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value * 1
    End If
Next rCell
```

Comment: Hi Mat, Thank you for your help. I tried using the code you shared above, still no success. Also, the code did not break. I noticed that when I manually select this column in excel and use "Convert Text to Columns Wizard" i.e. Alt + D + E + N + N + F shortcut, then the cells which are referencing column AQ in their formulas works fine and values gets populated as expected.

Comment: I've no idea where the "convert text to columns" comes into play here. Your question makes no mention of what the data is looking like, this answer assumes `rRange` contains one set of values that are usable as numbers. People that aren't looking at your screen can't guess what your data looks like.

Comment: The format of 'rRange' is text and i am trying to convert it to number. Thanks for your help :)